# How to import new invoices only from Quickbooks To MySQL Database?

Tags: php, quickbooks, devkit

I am using the QuickBooks PHP DevKit v2.0.0 and was wondering if it possible to import only new invoices into MySQL database rather than having to re-import existing data?

Currently I have only used the example MySQL mirror script to create my schema and import my data, which is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

> possible to import only new invoices into MySQL database rather than having to re-import existing data?

Yes, it's possible.

Nothing more we can tell you without seeing what you've done so far.

Comment: Great, so far I have just created the tables using the SQL mirror script without changing any of the table names or prefixes just the database connection details.

Comment: Could you let me know what you would need to see in order to provide me with some help? As mentioned before I would like to import only new invoices and line items

Comment: This is a website about programming. Your actual program code would be a reasonable place to start.

Comment: import script: https://drive.google.com/open?id=14T6HPJGwfJUjAYH8qww-ya5b1gCgoCXxNZIfx9ogzjM

Comment: import script: https://drive.google.com/open?id=14T6HPJGwfJUjAYH8qww-ya5b1gCgoCXxNZIfx9ogzjM

mirror script: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hdHHhV78J0fONqeVpkN-XnkAkGXcxP1q9FIUL0PSNv4

As mentioned previously I have mirrored the database perfectly using the above code provided by your framework. I just need help understanding your import code and modifying it to import new invoices only. 

When I try to run the current import code (linked above) quickbooks web connector throws the message "no data exchange required" even though there are new invoices in quickbooks that aren't synced.

Comment: Please post your code in the actual question, and not as a random Google drive link.